# How to handle IPv4 Address literals for IPv6-only network in iOS8

Tags: ios, networking, ios8, ipv6

I am implementing my application to be compatible for IPv6-only networks.
Is there any way to handle the hardcoded IPv4 address literals (such as 172.1.2.3) in iOS8.x ?

As per the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html),

*- In iOS 9 and later, NSURLSession and CFNetwork automatically synthesizes IPv6 addresses from IPv4 literals locally on devices operating on DNS64/NAT64 networks.*

*- The ability to synthesize IPv6 addresses was added to getaddrinfo() in iOS 9.2.*

But there is no mention of how to handle address literals for **iOS8.x**.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. Users using ancient iOS versions on modern networks connecting to legacy services will have connectivity problems. The best solutions are to:

- Never use hard-coded addresses in your code

  - There are many excellent reasons, just don't hard-code addresses and use DNS
  - If you use DNS then the NAT64 provider will handle the translation for you
- Make sure that your servers are reachable over both IPv4 and IPv6

  - This makes the reachability of your service much better
  - It makes NAT64 unnecessary, uses can just use native IPv6 without any hacks

If you want to run a good service and write a good App, do both of the above.

Comment: Some of the frameworks (such as XMPP) deals with hardcoded IP address literals. Using XMPP framework when I am connecting to XMPP client to XMPP server I need to use hardcoded literals . This issue is happening under IPv6 n/w for iOS 8.x .

Comment: In that case iOS 8 users will be out of luck

Comment: Presumably, any carrier or ISP that decides to deploy an IPv6-only network will inform its users that they need to use iOS 9.2+.